# At which circumstances can I omit curly braces in C?

Tags: c

I'm reading the famous K&R book and get stucked by the example in 1.6.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    printf("digits =");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);

    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Here why can the while statement work without curly braces? I know that if there is only one statement in the block then they can be omitted. But it seems to me that if...else if...else is not a single statement. Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: Well, the whole chain of if/else just *is* a single statement.

Comment: If the construct `if...else if...else` were not a single statement, it means there would be two statements at a minimum. It follows that you could insert as many extra semicolons as you wanted between those two statements. Can you insert extra semicolons *anywhere* within the construct? Try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax of the `while` statement is:

```
while ( expression ) statement
```

In C syntax a statement is either:

```
statement:
    labeled-statement
    compound-statement
    expression-statement
    selection-statement
    iteration-statement
    jump-statement
```

and a selection-statement is defined as:

```
selection-statement:
    if ( expression ) statement
    if ( expression ) statement else statement
    switch ( expression ) statement
```

So as you can see a `if` .. `else if` .. `else` is itself a statement.

You may also notice that a compound statement is itself a statement, so for example, this block:

```
{
    statement1;
    statement2;
}
```

is also a statement.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! That's very clear to me.

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting this from one of the C standards; if so, would this means that `else if` is not itself a "keyword" in C, but just a rather convenient consequence of the ability to omit curly braces?

Comment: @Frxstrem `else if` is not a keyword, it's a  `else` followed by a `if` which is allowed in C.

Answer (score -4):

If Curly Braces are removed from an expression, the expression will only be executed for a single statement.

Comment: That is unclear and ambiguous, and probably incorrect